# Shielding vs electron-electron repulsion

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, quantum-chemistry, electrons

**Example of shielding:**

[image: Shielding effect] ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_nuclear_charge))

The last electron in the 6s subshell of $\ce {Cs}$ is shielded from the nucleus by the inner electrons.

**Example of electron-electron repulsion:**

The electron affinity of $\ce F$ is surprisingly lower than that of $\ce{Cl}$. This is because, in $\ce F$, there are 5 electrons in the small-sized 2p subshell, so the electron density is very high. Therefore, the incoming electron is heavily repelled by the 5 electrons in the 2p subshell through electron-electron repulsion. So, the electron affinity of  $\ce F$ is lower.

**My comments:**

Can the example of electron-electron repulsion of $\ce F$ be called shielding? I previously knew that electrons in the same shell don't contribute to shielding; however, I found a [comment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22406/is-shielding-of-electrons-really-best-described-as-shielding-or-is-it-really-cou/22408#comment32759_22408) on the contrary.

**My questions:**

1. Do electrons in the same shell contribute to shielding?
2. Can the example of electron-electron repulsion in the case of $\ce F$ be called shielding?

Comment: As Q1: If you read [wikipedia.org : Slater's rules - Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_rules#Rules), you would see they do. Q2: In a way, yes, but the shielding is rather considered in context of affecting the mean radial force, while repulsion involves substantial tangential force.

Comment: E.g. an electron in the lobes of the orbital 2p_x  partially tangentially repulses electrons in 2p_y and 2p_z, and also eventually its mate in the same orbital, especially when in the same lobe.